# Android Mouse Motion Control App

Tags: android, motion

This is more of a general question i suppose...

I am looking to start to make an app which will connect to my pc via bluetooth and then control my mouse. I am wondering if any people know where to start or know of any places to get a tutorial from. I know basics about how to connect via bluetooth to a device, but dont have a clue where to being with motion conrol tutorials etc

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that you'll have to write an application on your pc that would communicate with the device and also with the mouse. There might be some sort of pc-side UI testing apps (analogs to Monkey) that you could harness for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tomcat Apache server or any other server which will receive mouse events sent from android mobile.